# Struggling to get Ubuntu to install

Tags: system-installation

I am very new to all of this so when trying to look through similar questions I'm not sure if they are the same problem.

I am trying to install Ubuntu via a flash drive. Whenever I do I get these messages and I'm struggling to find an answer as to why.

I get the message

```
DRM: failed to create a kernel channel,
device descriptor read/64 error -110,
No caching mode page found,
```

and then I get a soft lockup- CPU#1 stuck for 22s.

I cant seem to advance past this.

Apologies if I've laid this question out incorrectly. Would anyone mind explaining to me what I've done wrong?

Comment: You might want to show what hardware you are installing on...